# How do I remove UIAppearance settings from UILabel?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiappearance

How do I remove the setting of UIAppearance already set in UILabel?
Or How do I update already set up UIAppearance?

I created a custom defined UILabel method as follows.

Header

`- (void)setAppearanceFont:(UIFont *)font UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR;`

Implementation

```
- (void)setAppearanceFont:(UIFont *)font
{
    _invokeCount += 1;

    NSLog(@"invokeCount: %ld", _invokeCount);
    self.font = font;
}
```

If I set up appearance twice, setAppearanceFont method was invoked twice.

```
// set appearance
[[MyAppearanceLabel appearance] setAppearanceFont:font];
....
....
// set appearance from another timing
[[MyAppearanceLabel appearance] setAppearanceFont:font];

// show label
MyAppearanceLabel label* = [[MyAppearanceLabel alloc] 
                               initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
[self.view addSubview:label]; // <= invoked twice here!!
```

I want to ensure that the setAppearance method is invoked only once.

Comment: What's called twice when you call `addSubview:label`?

Comment: Ios calls setAppearanceFont:(UIFont *)font method twice when addSubView.

Comment: Wouldn't be simplest thing be for you to avoid calling `[[MyAppearanceLabel appearance] setAppearanceFont:font];` twice?

Comment: I want to change the appearance of the application dynamically. Therefore, I want to change appearance many times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In swift 4 i do as follow(just setting nil to it):

```
UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UITableViewCell.self]).textColor = nil
```